Using a named range in VBA
I'm trying to select worksheets to save as csv, was previously using an array that defined each sheet name but I was having to update the tab names each month.
I have a tab with the sheet names that I have defined as "TabNames", could anyone help me with the code as I'm getting a mismatch error
Sub EPMI()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Month As String

Dim vArray() As Variant
vArray = Range("TabNames")

Sheets(vArray("TabNames")).Select


Does Sheets(vArray).Select work?

Is the Range a single column ?

This code works for me:
    Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Month As String

Dim vArray As Variant
vArray = Range("TabNames").Value

Sheets(Application.Transpose(vArray)).Select

This because the vArray is going to be a 2d array so needs to be converted to a 1d.

fyi posted a MS365-addition to your valid answer.

As a further addition to myexceldeveloper-com 's valid answer:
If you are using MS365, you can also directly benefit from a formula like TOROW(TabNames) to get a 1dim sheets array.
Dim shts As Variant
shts = Evaluate("ToRow(TabNames,3)") ' e.g. 3 - ignore blanks or errors; 0 - keep all values (default)
Sheets(shts).Select


@ T.M. tnx, you are right. I am more VSTO Developer and always try to avoid Evaluate etc functions because speed/reliability :).

@MyExcelDeveloper.com tnx for feedback.  - btw speed wouldn't be a real criteria here; rather reliability because of versioning.
